# Dual boot only showing Windows8 and not ubuntu.

Tags: grub2, startup

I have installed latest ubuntu LTS with my bootfile in the efi directory as was showing for windows. But when I start the laptop it directly launches windows and doesn't show option for ubuntu. Although I somehow enabled the black screen at the beginning which is supposed to be let me choose OS but ot only shows windows8.1. I have repaired the grub and all but nothing works. What should I do.

Answer (score 0):

windows likes to put itself at the top of the boot order. a work around is this:

boot from a live CD. install efibootmgr.

find the file /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi. copy it to /efi/boot/bootx64.efi. if the file is there already move it to the windows folder (in case you want to restore windows boot late). this makes grub the default loader.

next use efibootmgr to delete all entries in the boot list. restart you computer, be sure ubuntu is the first OS you boot into so it is placed in the first slot.